# Geofence Sample Receiver issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app that uses geofences, and everything is working alright except for one thing:

My broadcast receiver inner class from the main class is not getting those intents which are notifying about geofence tranitions. However I get my notification alert from the `ReceiveTransitionsIntentService`
when I transit a geofence but I also want to set up a location change listener in the Main activity.
Ok, I'm going to show some code:

this is the `ReceiveTransitionsIntentService` (which work well) :

```
 public class ReceiveTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService  {

 public ReceiveTransitionsIntentService() {
 super("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService");
    }


protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

    if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {

        int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);

        String errorMessage = LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(
                this, errorCode);

        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                getString(R.string.geofence_transition_error_detail,
                        errorMessage));

        broadcastIntent
                .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)
                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, errorMessage);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
                broadcastIntent);

        // notification
    } else {

        int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

        if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

            List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient
                    .getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
            String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
            for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size(); index++) {
                geofenceIds[index] = geofences.get(index).getRequestId();
            }
            String ids = TextUtils.join(
                    GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER, geofenceIds);
            String transitionType = getTransitionString(transition);

            sendNotification(transitionType, ids);

            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(
                            R.string.geofence_transition_notification_title,
                            transitionType, ids));
            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));

        } else {
            // Always log as an error
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                            transition));
        }
    }
}


private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String ids) {
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

    Intent notificationIntent =
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GeofenceMain.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    stackBuilder.addParentStack(GeofenceMain.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);


            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                   .setSound(soundUri)
                   .setContentText(" This is a notification" )
                   .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);


            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
          }

private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
    switch (transitionType) {

    case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
        return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);

    case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
        return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);

    default:
        return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_unknown);
    }
}   
}
```

And this is a piece of code from my main activity , where i am not getting any information about a transition that happened.

```
   public class GeofenceMain extends FragmentActivity 
     {
           ...

      public class GeofenceSampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (TextUtils.equals(action, GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)) {

            handleGeofenceError(context, intent);

        } else if (TextUtils.equals(action,
                GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED)
                || TextUtils.equals(action,
                        GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCES_REMOVED)) {

            handleGeofenceStatus(context, intent);

        } else if (TextUtils.equals(action,
                GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)) {

            handleGeofenceTransition(context, intent);

        } else {
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(R.string.invalid_action_detail, action));
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.invalid_action,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private void handleGeofenceStatus(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //THIS ONE IS WORKING
    }


    private void handleGeofenceTransition(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //OVER HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
    }


    private void handleGeofenceError(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent
                .getStringExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS);
        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, msg);
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} }
```

Final words: I need some help to detect why I am not getting an intent which contains GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION action.